# Missing Ethernet Connection in Sharing Option

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, connection-sharing, sharing

I have a network connection and a wireless connection
Both of these connections are visible in the network and sharing area
The problem is that when I go to the sharing section on a wireless connection and want to share the internet over the network, I do not have the option to share this connection with another connection.

see the Pictures

it should be like below:

[image: SC1]

But it's like this:

[image: SC2]

Comment: What the detailed version of the windows 8.1? type `winver` to see the version number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Internet sharing with wireless cannot work because the hot-spot needs the antenna
and you can’t use it at the same time for both purposes.

What you can do is
[Use your PC as a mobile hotspot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027762/windows-use-your-pc-as-a-mobile-hotspot)
to share your Ethernet connection over WiFi:

1. Open *PC Settings  > Network & Internet > Mobile hotspot*
2. Under *Share my Internet connection from*, choose the Ethernet connection
3. Under *Share my Internet connection over* choose *Wi-Fi*
4. Select *Edit* and set the network name and password then click *Save*
5. On the top of the page, set to *On* the option of
   *Share my Internet connection with other devices*

Comment: bro i did this before and in previous version of my windows it worked but here not!

Comment: You can also try the alternate solution of [netsh wlan](http://faq.micro-pctech.com/2016/12/14/create-wifi-hotspot-using-command-prompt/).